# Join these 2 tables to get this specific output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014. I am working on a query where I want to extract information from 2 specific tables to create my final output.

An extract of the 2 tables (`Rebookings` and `ResaList`) are given below.

Rebookings Table (each CancelledID has its corresponding RebookingID):

```
CancelledID            RebookingID
  102                     541
  250                     351
  129                     800
  ...
```

ResaList Table:

```
ID      Property         ArrivalDate       RN
100       X              2020-05-22         9
102       X              2020-03-05         7
250       D              2020-04-12        10
129       E              2020-03-15         8
351       D              2020-09-23         5
541       X              2020-06-01         7
800       E              2020-07-11         8
...
```

Here is my desired output:

```
ID       Property        ArrivalDate         RN    RebookingID        Rebooking_ArrivalDate    Rebooking_RN     Tag
102         X            2020-03-05           7       541              2020-06-01                   7           Cancelled            
250         D            2020-04-12          10       351              2020-09-23                   5           Re-booked           
129         E            2020-03-15           8       800              2020-07-11                   8           Re-booked
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
USE [MyDatabase]

select    
  a.[ID],
  a.[Property],
  a.[Arrival Date],
  a.[RN],
  b.[RebookingID],
  (CASE WHEN a.[ID] in (SELECT [CancelledID] FROM [Rebookings]) THEN 'Re-booked'
      ELSE 'Cancelled'
      END) as [Tag]    
from [ResaList] a    
LEFT JOIN [Rebookings] b on b.[CancelledID] = a.[ID]       
where a.[ID] in (SELECT [CancelledID] FROM [Rebookings])        
GROUP BY a.[ID], a.[Property], a.[ArrivalDate], b.[RebookingID]
```

I am stuck at how to bring `Rebooking_ArrivalDate` and `Rebooking_RN` into the above output. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the same table twice by using aliases.

```
SELECT
    *
    ,(CASE WHEN b.[ID] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Re-booked'
      ELSE 'Cancelled'
      END) as [Tag]
FROM ResaList AS a
LEFT JOIN Rebookings ON a.ID = Rebookings.CancelledID
LEFT JOIN ResaList AS b ON b.ID = Rebookings.RebookingID
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in SQL Server.

```sql
DECLARE @cancelled Table (cancelledId int, rebookingId int)

INSERT into @cancelled values
(102    , 541  ),
( 250   ,  351 ),
( 129   ,  800 );

DECLARE @ResaList TABLE(Id int, property CHAR(1), ArrivalDate date, RN int)

INSERT INTO @ResaList values
(100  ,'X','2020-05-22',  9),
(102  ,'X','2020-03-05',  7),
(250  ,'D','2020-04-12', 10),
(129  ,'E','2020-03-15',  8),
(351  ,'D','2020-09-23',  5),
(541  ,'X','2020-06-01',  7),
(800  ,'E','2020-07-11',  8);


SELECT r.Id, r.Property, r.ArrivalDate, r.rn,
  rebooking.RebookingId
, rebooking.Rebooking_ArrivalDate
, rebooking.Rebooking_RN
, CASE WHEN rebooking.RebookingId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Re-booked' ELSE 'cancelled' end as tag
FROM @ResaList as r
OUTER APPLY (SELECT rc.Id, rc.ArrivalDate, rc.RN 
FROM @cancelled as c
INNER JOIN @ResaList AS rc
ON rc.Id = c.rebookingId
WHERE c.cancelledId = r.Id) as rebooking(RebookingId, Rebooking_ArrivalDate, Rebooking_RN)
```

```
+-----+----------+-------------+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
| Id  | Property | ArrivalDate | rn | RebookingId | Rebooking_ArrivalDate | Rebooking_RN |    tag    |
+-----+----------+-------------+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 100 | X        | 2020-05-22  |  9 | NULL        | NULL                  | NULL         | cancelled |
| 102 | X        | 2020-03-05  |  7 | 541         | 2020-06-01            | 7            | Re-booked |
| 250 | D        | 2020-04-12  | 10 | 351         | 2020-09-23            | 5            | Re-booked |
| 129 | E        | 2020-03-15  |  8 | 800         | 2020-07-11            | 8            | Re-booked |
| 351 | D        | 2020-09-23  |  5 | NULL        | NULL                  | NULL         | cancelled |
| 541 | X        | 2020-06-01  |  7 | NULL        | NULL                  | NULL         | cancelled |
| 800 | E        | 2020-07-11  |  8 | NULL        | NULL                  | NULL         | cancelled |
+-----+----------+-------------+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using select in an inner query to find out existing records is very bad way to do this. On larger tables you will suffer a lot.
Here is a compact and efficient way-

```
    select
    a.ID,
    a.Property,
    a.Arrival Date,
    a.RN,
    b.RebookingID,
    b.Rebooking_ArrivalDate,
    b.Rebooking_RN,
    coalesce(b.tag,'Cancelled')as tag
from ResaList a left join
    (
    select *, 'Re-booked' as tag from Rebookings
    ) b 
    on a.ID=b.CancelledID
```